# Algorithm to find a block in a 2D matrix

Tags: 2d

I want to find a block in a 2D matrix. Inside this matrix there's only one block of any size, or nothing. If there's a block, it will always be connected to two angles of the matrix. Let me show you a couple of valid samples.

```
----------------XXXX
----------------XXXX
----------------XXXX
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
```

Another one

```
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
--------------------
-------------XXXXXXX
-------------XXXXXXX
-------------XXXXXXX
```

What's the most efficient algorithm to find the position/size of the block? I'm using a loop that traverses both arrays but it's slow as hell!

Comment: Hello, welcome to the party! Congratulations on your first question. One note though: You don't need to say "thanks", it's superfluous and sometimes considered noise. You can edit it out if you want. Have fun on this stack.

Comment: @Richard could you post an example of your loop, which is currently slow? There are approaches to reduce 2 dimensional grids into a one dimensional array which makes the algorithms scaleable to linear growth. When you post your code we may be able to come up with a O(N) solution for your problem.